# LibreCalc: Change background color

Tags: colors, conditional-formatting, libreoffice-calc

I have 3 columns: R G B. I want the 4th column to have the background color corresponding the the RGB in the first 3 columns.

So sort of:

```
<td bgcolor="#"+A1*10000+B1*100+C1> Cell content </td>
```

How do I do that?

I have found conditional formatting, but it seems that does not make it possible to compute RGB value I want.

Comment: The only way to do this would be using a macro, but since a macro isn't allowed to modify the sheet from which it was called, it won't work - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/33414461/342546 :-(

Answer (score 2):

The following solution is somewhat awkward because it requires a separate sheet, as explained in @tohuwawohu's comment.

First, go to `Tools -> Macros -> Organize Macros -> LibreOffice Basic` and add the following user-defined function somewhere in Standard macros.

```vb
Function BGCOLOR(rgb_array, address)
    Dim red, green, blue As Integer
    Dim positionOfMatch As Integer
    Dim sheet_name, cell_name As String
    Dim oSheet, oCell As Object
    red = rgb_array(1, 1)
    green = rgb_array(1, 2)
    blue = rgb_array(1, 3)
    positionOfMatch = InStr(address, ".")
    sheet_name = Mid(address, 2, positionOfMatch - 2)  'start after initial $
    cell_name = Right(address, Len(address) - positionOfMatch)
    oSheet = ThisComponent.getSheets().getByName(sheet_name)
    oCell = oSheet.getCellRangeByName(cell_name)
    oCell.CellBackColor = RGB(red, green, blue)
    BGCOLOR="BG Color for " & address
End Function
```

Then, as an example, start a new Calc spreadsheet and enter `=RANDBETWEEN(0,255)` in A1.  Drag and fill this formula down to C10.

Next, add a new sheet.  Enter in cell A1 of the new sheet:

```
=BGCOLOR($Sheet1.A1:C1, CELL("ADDRESS", $Sheet1.D1))
```

These addresses can also be entered automatically by clicking in the formula, going to that sheet and selecting the range or cell.  However,  `BGCOLOR` may try to run while you're still editing the formula, which can be annoying.

Finally, drag the formula down to A10.  Here is an example of how sheet 1 looks as a result.

[image: ten colors on sheet 1]

A similar question was asked at https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/21081/using-libreoffice-calc-dynamically-set-the-background-color-of-a-cell-to-the-hex-value-in-that-cell/.